# How do I install the Rappture Java bindings on a HUB built from the Open Source recipe?

Tags: java

I have followed the instructions for installing a HUB using the Debian package approach. I’ve installed Java on the VM and have it running in a workspace. Now I would like to install the Java bindings for Rappture. Is there a recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used new version of rappture with java bindings. I’ve tested the following installation steps and it should go well.

First, change the /etc/apt/sources.list file. Find the lines pointing to our repository at packages.hubzero.org and change the ‘lenny’ to ‘buck’. ‘buck’ is our testing repository. Don’t change any of the lines for the standard debian repositories.

Next run: apt-get update

Now remove the old version by running: dpkg —purge hubzero-rappture then run: ls -la /apps/rappture You will still see a dated directory for previous version of rappture but it won’t do any harm if you leave it. If there are any links left in that directory then remove those since they’ll cause the new install to fail.

Lastly, run the command: apt-get install hubzero-rappture and your new version should be installed.

To test the new rappture, start a workspace and copy the directory /apps/rappture/examples into your own local directory. Then cd into that the local copy of the directory and run the command: ./demo.bash fermi This will run several version of the fermi demo one of which will be a java version.